# Alert program for logging into Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, console-application

I've created a simple console app that will be used to send an email every time a server is logged into remotely. It will be used for auditing purposes and detecting logins without the need for checking log files which could be modified.

How do I install the app on the server, and how do I invoke the exe at login, without installing as a service or some other noticeable process?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a scheduled task that sends an email whenever anyone logs on. (Windows Server 2008 can even send the email itself, but in that case I don't know whether you can tell who the user that logged on was.)